# User activation registration with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a registration system with CodeIgniter. I have a controller called User with the following code:

```
class User extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        if(($this->session->userdata('user_name')!=""))
        {
            $this->welcome();
        }
        else{
            $data['title']= 'Home';
            $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
            $this->load->view("registration_view.php", $data);
            $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
        }
    }
    public function welcome()
    {
        $data['title']= 'Welcome';
        $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('welcome_view.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=md5($this->input->post('pass'));

        $result=$this->user_model->login($email,$password);
        if($result) $this->welcome();
        else        $this->index();
    }
    public function thank()
    {
        $data['title']= 'Thank';
        $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('thank_view.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
    }
    public function registration()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('con_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->user_model->add_user();
            $this->thank();
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $newdata = array(
        'user_id'   =>'',
        'user_name'  =>'',
        'user_email'     => '',
        'logged_in' => FALSE,
        );
        $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata );
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

So far so good. If I go to the register page I get the registration form displayed. If I send the form and it passes the form validation checks, I get the success page, if the form has errors, I get the form back with some error messages.

Now what I want to do is the database stuff. I have some idea of how I can get the POST values from the registration form into my database, but no clue how I can check if a username or email already exists, and if so, display that error on the registration form. and when i register in form, how can i send activation to user email to active account in my site.

Here's my registration form view:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="signup_wrap">
<div class="signin_form">
    <?php echo form_open("user/login"); ?>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" />
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value="" />
        <input type="submit" class="" value="Sign in" />
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div><!--<div class="signin_form">-->
</div><!--<div class="signup_wrap">-->
<div class="reg_form">
<div class="form_title">Sign Up</div>
<div class="form_sub_title">It's free and anyone can join</div>
<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?>
    <?php echo form_open("user/registration"); ?>
        <p>
            <label for="user_name">User Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" />
        </p>        
        <p>
            <label for="email_address">Your Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" value="<?php echo set_value('email_address'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="con_password">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="con_password" name="con_password" value="<?php echo set_value('con_password'); ?>" />
        </p>        
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="greenButton" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div><!--<div class="reg_form">-->    
</div><!--<div id="content">-->
```

and module is :-

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function login($email,$password)
    {
        $this->db->where("email",$email);
        $this->db->where("password",$password);

        $query=$this->db->get("user");
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $rows)
            {
                //add all data to session
                $newdata = array(
                        'user_id'       => $rows->id,
                        'user_name'     => $rows->username,
                        'user_email'    => $rows->email,
                        'logged_in'     => TRUE,
                   );
            }
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
                return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function add_user()
    {
        $data=array(
            'username'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email_address'),
            'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password'))
            );
        $this->db->insert('user',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: For username or email exists validation you can extend the CI validation library in your application/libraries folder then have your own functions. Then you can use it same way as you do with CI validation function. DB stuff has be to done in model rule. Sending email needs to be using the email helper.

Comment: @Nish how can i use email helper to send activation

Comment: $CI->load->library('email');
    $CI->email->initialize($CI->config->item('email_config'));
    $CI->email->from($from, $fromName);
    $CI->email->to($to);
    $CI->email->subject($subject);
    $CI->email->message($body);
    $CI->email->send();

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|is_unique[users.user_name]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|valid_email|is_unique[users.email_address]');
```

If your `Form_validation.php` does not have `is_unique()` function, then add:

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
{
    list($table, $field) = explode('.', $field);

    if (isset($this->CI->db))
    {
        $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));
        return $query->num_rows() === 0;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: users.email or users.email_address ??

Comment: sorry, its email_address

Comment: i will try but its show me error that "The User Name field is required. " my input type is <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" />

Comment: i have this message error when use  function is_unique to show it found on DB or not Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.