# Account activation, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mysql-workbench, activation

I want to create an account activation where after registering, a link would be sent to an administrator (or one) email whereby the admin just has to click that link to activate that account.

I have the registration and login working. I'm using MySQL Workbench and have a "flag" or rather just a field in my accounts table (named `user_login`) to tell whether the account is enabled or disabled, which is disabled by default after registration.

I am stuck and sending a link through email, I'm not sure where to begin. That link that I want to send would contain a random string and would be sent to the admin, say `abc/123/random?stringis=1234`. Then the admin would just have to open his email and click on the string and then that specific user's account would be activated. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508339/codeigniter-email-verification-pass-parameters) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268501/user-activation-registration-with-codeigniter) but that's just for how to send a link through email.

I don't have an idea on the logic. Do I create a function whereby the link would go directly to the function and from there, it would change the value in my table to `enabled` or whatever I call it so that the user's account is counted as activated? Do I need to create a new field to match the random generated string then?

Main idea is I'm trying to do like those typical sites whereby a link would be sent to the user to activate the account once he/she clicks it in the email, but this time just to a specific email which is the admin's.

EDIT:

In controller

```
public function activate_user($activation_code)
{
    $result = $this->home_model->activate($activation_code);

    if($result != FALSE)
    {
        echo "You have activated :".$result[0]->user_id.".";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Activation failed, something went wrong.";
    }
}
```

In Model:

```
public function activate($activation_link)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_login');
    $this->db->where('activation_link', $activation_link);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First

> Database
>   add two column

- activation_token{varchar|255}
- activation_time{datetime}

> After registration Success

- add some randome has into activation_token(md5 or sha1(up to you))
- add time if registration using Current timestamp(now())

> Link

link should be
I strongly prefer userid in activation url
because it's remove the link duplication. 
http://sitename.com/activation/{user_id}/{hash}

in controller

```
public function activation($user_id,$hash)
{

  $timeOfexpiration = 3600;

  $data = $this->model->get_data($id,$hash);

  if(!$data)
  {
    return false
  }

    //if user found 
    //check expiration of linke
    //like

  if($data['activation_time']+$timeOfexpiration < now())
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: 3600 second means 1 minutes . its in seconds. it's depend on you how much you want.Best practice is define constant for that.

Comment: for 24 hour use 60*60*24

Answer (score 2):

for that you need to add one more field in table called `activation_link`when user register in site then generate random string and store that in `activation_link` and send link to the user so once user back then check the link and activate that user.

Comment: Ohhh, okay I'll try that first.

Comment: Humm... let me know if you have issue with that.

Comment: Okay wait, but how do I code the link containing the parameters? Because I want to access it in the new function I created to "activate".

Comment: if you have added code for the login controller and activate method then your url will be `http://domain.com/login/activate/ {youractivationlinkcode}` and activation function should be  `function activate($activationLinkCode)`

Comment: I am a little confused at your last comment but I edited in what I've done. So you're saying at `{youractivationlinkcode}` is where I can get my code? I don't have to use anything like `$_GET`? The code would automatically be passed to the function?

Comment: Yes you need not add after ? it will automatically link comes in `$activationLinkCode` variable